# How to open another window

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to open in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242908/how-to-open-in-new-window)

how can i open a page in new window in using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this piece of code:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

That's if you want to open a new window.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

You can call it like this:

```
<a href="something.html" onclick="return popitup('something.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

You can attach the code as a client-side event on a button.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use plain old html and the target attribute. `<a href="link.html" target="_blank">`