# how to open in new window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have another problem :(
this is my script

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function first()
    {
        var first = confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?");
            if (first)
                window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com.sg"
            else
            window.close;
    }
    function second()
    {
        var second = confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?");
        if (second)
            window.location = "http://www.google.com"
        else
            window.close;
    }
</script>


<p><b>Click the following link to enter yahoo</b></p>
<p><a href="javascript:first()"title="Opens in an external website in a new window">yahoo</a></p>

<p><b>Click the following link to check google</b></p>
<p><a href="javascript:second()" title="Opens in an external website in a new window">google</a></p>
```

its doesnt open in a new window.
please i need some help. any suggestion or recommendation?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). This will open a new window:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

See also:

- [MDN: `window.open` usability issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#Usability_issues)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `window.open` method and specify `_blank` as the target:

```
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com.sg', '_blank');
```

This will open the page in a new window or a new tab, depending on the user settings in the browser.

If you want it to open in a new popup window always, you can specify a parameter string with width and height for the window. However, most browsers will block such a popup that opens a page from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening in a new window, you don't need to check with the user about navigating away.

```
function first()
    {
           window.open("http://www.yahoo.com.sg")
    }
    function second()
    {
        window.open"http://www.google.com")
    }
```